# Writing a method to not show private resource unless it's current users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my `Product` model that has the attribute `private`. I want to make a method that allows the current user to be able to select their private products and others that are  `private = false` only.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :private
  belongs_to :user

  def permission
    unless self.current_user
      unless self.private
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does it start out like this? How would I write this method? The goal is to put this inside of a select menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class method for this which you would pass something like `current_user` to

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :private
  belongs_to :user

  def self.for_user_or_public(user)
    where("user_id = ? or private = ?", user.id, false)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
products = Product.for_user_or_public(current_user)
```

As for the select, something like the following should work

```
<%= f.collection_select :owner_id, Product.for_user_or_public(current_user), :user_id, :name, { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Comment: What about for a select menu? `<%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => true }, { } %>`. If I was to select a product?

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited it real quick, that was from another form I have.